# what kind of swift datatypes we can not communicate/call from objectiveC code?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

This question is regarding calling Swift methods from Objective-C code.

What kind of Swift objects we can not communicate/call from Objective-C code?

I have come across one ie Tuple. since objective C doesn't have Tuple equivalent datatype, we can not call a swift method that takes/returns Tuple from Objective-C code.

Are there any other datatypes?

Comment: do you know about `@objc` directive used with swift functions?

Comment: yes i know about @objc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Objective-C can’t see any of the following:

- Swift enums, except for an @objc enum with an Int raw value
- Swift structs, except for structs that come ultimately from C (or that are bridged)
- Swift classes not derived from NSObject
- Swift protocols not marked @objc
- Protocol extensions
- Generics
- Tuples
- Nested types